# how can i disable safe mode for php on web server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server, php5, php.ini

I am using **wkhtmltopdf** for making a pdf of a page. My code executes the shell to run a command using this **wkhtmltopdf** library. Everything works fine in my wamp server but when the code runs on my web-server it does not work and gives the following error:

```
Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/pssptech/public_html/.../cert.php on line 272
```

I think that the php is running on safe mode on the server that's why the shell execution is disabled. But the main problem is I am unable to find the **php.ini** file on my **remote web-server.**
Can you tell me where can I find the config file so that I can disable the safe mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Danger Will Robinson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your php.ini and set the variable safe_mode to off.

```
safe_mode = Off
```

To find php.ini in linux run

> find / -name php.ini -print

Comment: Can you please tell me from where can I run this command on my remote web-server?

Comment: You should run this command in terminal. What kind of access do you have in your server?

Comment: The server is a shared one so I only have ftp access.

Comment: Can you try to add "php_value safe_mode off" in your .htaccess and check if it helps?

Comment: I just tried it and it gave me "Internal Server Error" (error code:500)

Comment: @user1767434 then you'll need to ask your host to change it for you, and if they won't, then you'll need to change to a different host.

Comment: In current version of PHP (7.1.8), there is no more `safe_mode` option. There is only `sql.safe_mode`. Is this the same?